# "Starting new Thread in constructor" warning in Lambda expression (NetBeans IDE)

Tags: java, netbeans, lambda, thread-safety

When I start new thread in traditional constructor, NetBeansIDE gives no warnings:

```
addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        (new SomeThread()).start();
    }
});
```

But if I convert it to Lambda expression, I'm getting a warning "Starting new Thread in constructor":

```
addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

   (new SomeThread()).start();
});
```

What is the problem here? What is the correct solution?

**EDIT 1:**

The same problem on NetBeans IDE 8.0.2:

[image]

The code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerClass extends Timer {

    public TimerClass() {
        super(1000, null);//Loop 1 sec

        addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

            (new SomeClass()).start();
        });

    }

    private class SomeClass extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in NetBeans diagnostics.

Comment: It's just a warning, which I guess should be configurable (I'm not sure though). Please check out the warning configuration in NetBeans, you might find something.

Comment: Yes, but it must be a reason for this..

Comment: The reason is that the NetBeans code that shows the "Starting new Thread in constructor" warning was written before Java 8 existed, and was not properly updated when support for Java 8 syntax was added to NetBeans.

Comment: Yes, it could be, since I'm using NetBeans 7.4, I will try on 8.0.2 and will let you know.

Comment: Did you check if javac is giving you similar warnings? (I also assume that there is no specific reason but the version of the tool you are using).

Comment: No, but in project properties JDK 1.8 is selected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that it's considered dangerous to start a thread or even register a listener in a constructor. 
Explanation:
An inner class contains a reference to its enclosing class meaning that the thread that you started in your constructor has a reference to the `TimerClass` object's state **before** the constructor returned. So the new thread might see a partially constructed object with stale values (values that are current in one thread but not for others). 
A simple fix:
 Make the constructor private and then make a public and static factory method that creates the object and starts the thread.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerClass extends Timer {

    // notice that the constructor is now private.
    private TimerClass() {
        super(1000, null);  //Loop 1 sec
    }

    // This will create the instance and then register the listener and start the thread
    public static TimerClass createInstance() {

        TimerClass instance = new TimerClass();       
        instance.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

            (instance.new SomeClass()).start();
        });

        return instance;
    }

    private class SomeClass extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }
}
```

With this, the thread will see a *fully constructed* object and thread safety will be restored (thus removing the warning).